# Flink JobManager HA on Kubernetes

Tags: apache-flink

The latest [Flink 1.9 doc](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/jobmanager_high_availability.html#bootstrap-zookeeper) on JobManager HA only covers Standalone and YARN. I'm looking for how to enable HA on Kubernetes.

Answer (score 2):

Deploy Flink on K8s uses the Standalone mode, you just need to add HA config to your flink-conf.yaml:

```
high-availability: zookeeper
high-availability.zookeeper.quorum: localhost:2181
high-availability.zookeeper.path.root: /flink
high-availability.cluster-id: /cluster_one # important: customize per cluster
high-availability.storageDir: hdfs:///flink/recovery
```

How to create Docker image:
https://github.com/apache/flink/tree/release-1.9/flink-container/docker

Helm chart:
https://github.com/docker-flink/examples

if you use helmchart to deploy your job, you can just add the HA configurations in the values.yaml:

```
flink:
  num_taskmanagers: 3
  config: |
    high-availability: zookeeper
    high-availability.zookeeper.quorum: localhost:2181
    high-availability.zookeeper.path.root: /flink
    high-availability.cluster-id: /cluster_one # important: customize per cluster
    high-availability.storageDir: hdfs:///flink/recovery
```

Comment: Thanks! Do I need to first deploy a ZooKeeper in the cluster, or can I simply run the ZooKeeper included in Flink?

Comment: I'm not sure if zookeeper is included in Flink, it's better to install one

Comment: See https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/jobmanager_high_availability.html#bootstrap-zookeeper